# How can I find the equivalence class?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The task is to find the equivalence classes of this relations (I have not a single clue):

a) $$(x,y), (u,v) \in \mathbb{R^2}: (x,y)\sim(u,v): \Leftrightarrow x-y = u-v$$
b) $$x,y \in \mathbb{R}: (x\sim y): \Leftrightarrow x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Thanks for help!

Comment: Does the symbol $:\Leftrightarrow$ have some special semantics here, or is it a typo somehow?

Comment: This is what I found in the lecture notes but I guess it means that the equivalence relation is defined as...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we want you to do some work I will give you the answers and you have to prove them

- a) $C_k=\left\{(x,y) \big/ x-y=k\right\}$ where $k\in \mathbb{R}$
- b) $C_a=a+\mathbb Z=\{a+k\big /k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thank you so much...
Do things change if I tell you that $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$?

Comment: nothing changes just the indexes $k$ and $a$ will be element of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: So according to a) I can see that $k$ is the difference of $x$ and $y$...
A equivalence class consists of elements which are equal to (x,y) (have the same properties), in this special case have the same difference...
So in the euqivalence class of $(x,y)$ there must be all elements with the same difference $k$ - is this true?

Comment: yes this is exactly the reasoning and the idea (if you want to do things more formally you can use double inclusion to prove it using the definition you have in the book for an equivalence class)

Comment: But this can't be that simple I guess...

Just to be sure I totally understood:
a) The equivalence class consists of all elements $(x,y)$ which have the difference of $k$.
b) The equivalence class consists of all elements $x-y$ which are an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, when $x$ and $y$ are actually rational numbers.

Comment: The second question: the class of $a$ consists of all elements which differs from $a$ by an integer hence those of the form $a+k$ with $k$ is an integer formally: if $(a\sim x)$ then $a-x=k$ for some integer $k$ and $x=a+(-k)$ hence $x\in C_a$, now if $x\in C_a$ then $x-a$ is an integer thus $a\sim x$

Comment: Oh, thank you so much - I now understand this :D THANKS!